# R issues vs excel

Tags: r

I am working on a project where I have multiple excel files and each file is having multiple workbook,  I have to get the data from one of the workbook let say `sheet=6`, and after that all theses data to store in a new `.xls` or `.csv` file.

I am facing issue while trying to read the data from file and string it in to list. getting the following error:

```
Error: `path` does not exist: ‘BillingReport___Gurgaon-Apr-2019.xlsx’
```

I am trying mapdfr funtion ot get the data.

```
library(purrr)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(rio)
library(XLConnect)
library(tidyverse)

setwd ="F:/Capstone/Billing Reports final/"

#Set path of Billing source  folder
billingptah <- "F:/Capstone/Billing Reports final/"

#Set path of destination  folder
csvexportpath <- "F:/Capstone/Billing_data/billing_data.csv"

#get the names of the files to be loaded
files_to_load <-   list.files(path = billingptah)

files_to_load

#Load all the data into one file

billing_data <- map_dfr(files_to_load, function(x) map_dfr( excel_sheets(x) , function(y) read_excel(path=x, sheet = 6,col_types = "text" ) %>% mutate(sheet=6)  ) %>% mutate(filename=x) )
```

following is the error message:

```
Error: `path` does not exist: 
‘BillingReport___Gurgaon-Apr-2019.xlsx’
```

Comment: have you checked the answers?

Comment: sir my apologies for responding late, my laptop got crashed, i have tried the solution you provided and it worked well except the main heading row is included in the data set with NA columns.. i need to explore more about map function and its utilities. can you please suggest?

Comment: No problem. That is weird, because `read_excel()`s default is to read the first line as header. Is the header line the same in every file? Maybe you can provide the header in your question?

Answer (score 0):

It is all about the difference about relative and absolute path. You're telling R to load a file located in your current working directory named `‘BillingReport___Gurgaon-Apr-2019.xlsx’`. You need to add the path to access this file name as a suffix. Try this after building `files_to_load`:

```
files_to_load <- paste0(billingptah, files_to_load)
```

It will tell R to access the files named after `file_to_load` located in `billingptah` directory.

**Edit**

Let me just point you out some useful links:

- https://www.reed.edu/data-at-reed/resources/R/reading_and_writing.html
- And for best practices: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/file.path.html